# Redundant duplication of typealiase declarations when conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift, collections, type-alias, swift-keypath

```
protocol PathCollection: Collection where Element == Target.Element, Index == Target.Index {
    associatedtype Target: Collection
    static var reference: KeyPath<Self, Target> { get }
}

extension PathCollection {
    private var target: Target { self[keyPath: Self.reference] }
    
    var startIndex: Index { target.startIndex }
    var endIndex: Index { target.endIndex }

    subscript(index: Index) -> Element {
        get { target[index] }
    }

    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        target.index(after: i)
    }
}
```

It's pretty useful protocol which helps us to reduce boilerplate code when creating custom collections.
Suppose our struct wraps a dictionary. And we want it to be a collection just like that dictionary.
We should provide keyPath to the dictionary property and apply to the protocol. And it works!
Example of usage and my question:

```
protocol Graph: PathCollection where Target == [String: Int] {
    var storage: [String: Int] { get set }
}

extension Graph {
    static var reference: KeyPath<Self, [String: Int]> { \.storage }
}

struct UndirectedGraph: Graph {
    typealias Element = Dictionary<String, Int>.Element // Why should we again declare this typealias!?
    typealias Index = Dictionary<String, Int>.Index // Why should we again declare this typealias!?

    var storage: [String: Int]
}
```

It perfectly works. But why should we redeclare Element and Index typealiases!? At the very first line of code of this post we explicitly defines Element and Index:

```
protocol PathCollection: Collection where Element == Target.Element, Index == Target.Index {
```

and then:

```
protocol Graph: PathCollection where Target == [String: Int] {
```

If I remove that redeclarations I get an compilation error, which I don't understand:

> 'PathCollection' requires the types 'Slice' and
> 'Dictionary<String, Int>.Element' (aka '(key: String, value: Int)') be
> equivalent

Comment: Turns out you don't need to rewrite both of the type aliases. Just one is enough for the compiler to figure out. But still, this is strange.